# Magento2: Incorrect CAPTCHA Issue

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.4.6

I am getting incorrect captcha error, I am using by default captcha of magento version 2.4.6-p3. As I removed all the custom modules(even which is not related to captcha) and design theme changes. Not getting entries in captcha_log table. As I debug it is generating 2 times like screenshot below but it is verifying 2nd one and dispaying 1st one.
[image: Successfully verifying 2nd one]
[image: Displaying 1st one]

I tried in vanilla magento 2.4.6 but it is working properly and having entry in captcha_log table.

**NOTE:** If I click on Reload Captcha button it will work.

Comment: Hi @Ankit
Is the issue fixed or you still facing the same issue?